# How to add a Domain Alias for Email (only) Hosting

Tags: plesk

I know how to define a Domain Alias and use him for Email too.
Eg. I setup someone@domain1.com account and a email to the alias domain2 goes in the same account.

but how can i do that, without a (web) hosting, just email in Plesk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it a forwarder. You go to you settings and forward `info@domain1.com` to `info@domain2.com`, and it will do exactly what you ask.

A forwarder is about the same as an alias.